# How to compute a 2-variable infinite sum with factorials in the numerator and denominator?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to compute

$\begin{align*}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\sum^{\infty}_{t=0}(3k+5t+2)\left(\frac{1}{2}^k\frac{1}{3}^t\frac{(k+t)!}{k!t!}\frac{1}{6}\right)\end{align*}$, which is supposed to give me the expected value for some random variable.

The furthest step I could achieve was

$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{6}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{1}{2}^k\frac{1}{k!}\left((3k+2)\sum^{\infty}_{t=0}\left(\frac{1}{3}^t\frac{(k+t)!}{t!}\right)+5\sum^{\infty}_{t=-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}^{t+1}\frac{(k+t+1)!}{t!}\right)\right)\end{align*}$,

which is actually basic algebra. I know how to calculate 
$\begin{align*} \sum^{\infty}_{t=0}\frac{1}{3}^t\end{align*}$ and$\begin{align*}\sum^{\infty}_{t=0}\frac{1}{3}^tt  \end{align*}$ by multiplying by $\frac{1}{3}$ and then subtracting etc. but I am having trouble when it comes to higher powers, and then I need to find a way to incorporate $k$ so that I get $\begin{align*} \sum^{\infty}_{t=0}\frac{1}{3}^t(t+1)(t+2)\cdots (t+k-1)(t+k).  \end{align*}$ At least that's what I believe. Are there any tips? Wolfram computes this to 21, so I believe there must be at least some algebraic way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By re-writing $(k+t)!$ as $\int_{0}^{+\infty} u^{k+t}e^{-u}\,du $ the given double series turns into

$$ \frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-u}\sum_{k,t\geq 0}(3k+5t+2)\frac{u^k}{2^k k!}\cdot\frac{u^t}{3^t t!}\,du = \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-u}\frac{12+19u}{36}e^{5u/6}\,du$$
and the computation of the last integral is straightforward: it equals $\color{red}{21}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you be please kind enough to explain the steps you took to get from the LFS to the RHS?

Comment: @user126605: the key ingredient are just $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{k u^k}{2^k k!}=\frac{u}{2}e^{u/2}, \sum_{t\geq 0}\frac{t u^t}{3^t t!}=\frac{u}{3}e^{u/3}$$ and $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{u^k}{2^k k!}=e^{u/2}, \sum_{t\geq 0}\frac{u^t}{3^t t!}=e^{u/3}$$

Comment: If you write $\sum_{k,t\geq 0}(3k+5t+2)H(t,k)$ as the sum of three series, you may apply Fubini's theorem to each one of the components, then combine the outcomes into the shown RHS.